# How to capture a signature from an ePad in C# - windows forms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, input-devices, epad

I need to save a signature from an [ePad device](http://www.epadlink.com/solutions-epadhardware-epad.php) .. I would prefer to use the `Microsoft.Ink` `InkPicture` control but the ePad really zoom zooms the mouse pointer about.  The ePad SDK samples didn't compile either.  Also, I'm a winforms noob.  Is there a certain library or sample code that might be helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Your signature device comes with COM driver (found it in tech specification). 
From examples you may find how to connect and enable device.

I'm not sure that you can operate the device via InkPicture control.

An another option is OPOS, but you have to ask device vendor if the device supports OPOS.